# Laravel 4: Route::post return URL with model name in brackets instead of id

Tags: laravel-4

I am building a post/comment system, with the comment form inside the post view. So, when I'm watching a post in the url `http://example.dev/post/1` and click on the form submit buttom the url goes to `http://example.dev/post/%7Bpost%7D` where `%7B` = `{` and `%7D` = `}`).

I think the controller associated to the url post method doesn't even start.

My routes:

```
Route::model('post','Post');

Route::get('partido/{post}', 'FrontendController@viewPost');

Route::post('partido/{post}', array(
    'before' => 'basicAuth',
    'uses' => 'FrontendController@handleComment'
    )
);
```

My viewPost controller:

```
public function viewPost(Post $post)
{   
    $comments = $post->comments()->get();

    return View::make('post')
                    ->with(compact('comments'))
                    ->with(compact('posts'));
}
```

My handleComment controller:

```
public function handleComment(Post $post)
    {
        // Get the data
        $data = Input::all();
        // Build the rules
        $rules = array(
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        );
        // Error messages
        $messages = array(
            'title.required' => 'Title required.',
            'description.required' => 'Description required.',
        );

        // Validator: He Comes, He sees, He decides
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            // Save the new comment.
           $comment = new Comment;
           $comment->title = Input::get('title');
           $comment->description = Input::get('description');
           $post->comments()->save($comment);

           return Redirect::to('post/'.$post->id.'');
        }
       else {
           return Redirect::to('post/'.$post->id.'')->withErrors($validator);
       }
    }
```

And the form in the view:

```
{{ Form::open(array(
    'action'       => 'FrontendController@handleComment', $post->id
)) }}
    <ul class="errors">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
    {{ Form::label('title', 'Title')}}<br />
    {{ Form::text('title', '', array('id' => 'title')) }}
    <br />
    {{ Form::label('description', 'Description')}}<br />
    {{ Form::textarea('description', '', array('id' => 'description')) }}
    <br />
    {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another array for the `Form::open()` - try this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('FrontendController@handleComment', $post->id))) }}
```

Comment: That was it. Ugh, I feel a little dummy now. Thanks :)